# Outlook error "there was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/..."

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

A number of our users (with differing versions of MS Outlook and in different locations) are occasionally receiving an error message (screenshot attached):

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   net.pipe://localhost/{string}/{string} that could accept the message. 
>   This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
>   InnerException, if present, for more details.

It apparently only occurs every few weeks and does not appear to have any effect on the function of Outlook.

It would be good to know what is causing it though and how to stop it occurring again.

We're using hosted Exchange Online by Microsoft Office 365 and do not have an on-prem Exchange server.

[image]

Comment: What does Office365 support say about the error?

Comment: I'm still waiting for a reply from them.
I was hoping someone might have a fix while I'm waiting (forever waiting)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this while developing an application using named pipes.

For me, the solution was to turn on named pipes in `Turn Windows features on or off` > `.NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services` > `WCF Services` > `Named Pipe Activation`.

This was on Windows 10 with some developer features installed, so it might not be available to your users, but maybe gives someone a starting point for the solve.

[image]